# java Reuse existing object

Tags: java, object, reusability

I can solve this problem using singleton pattern. But problem is I don't have control on other application which is going to call new MyClass().
 Is there any way I can do in implicit constructor of MyClass?.
 Something like this.

```
class ClassName {
    public ClassName() {
        if( object exist for ClassName)
            return that
        else
            create New ClassName object
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). You have to hide the standard constructor, so no one else can call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a enum:

```
public enum ClassName {
    INSTANCE;

}
```

Now, you have one instance and you don't have to worry about others instantiating your class.

---

> Is there any way I can do in implicit constructor of MyClass?.

No, that can't be done in a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control construction, put in an explicit constructor and declare it private. You can call it from a static factory method, in the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
public class MySingletonClass {
    private static MySingletonClass instance = null;
    private MySingletonClass() { }
    public static MySingletonClass getInstance() {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = new MySingletonClass();
       }
       return instance;
    }
    // add your methods here.
}
```

This way nobody can call `new MySingletonClass();`. To get the one and only instance of the object you have to write:

```
MySingletonClass msc = MySingletonClass.getInstance();
```

or use it somehow like this for `void` methods:

```
MySingletonClass.getInstance().yourMethod();
```

or like this for Methods with a return type:

```
VariableType foo = MySingletonClass.getInstance().yourMethod(); // Must return VariableType
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable in your class and hold your `object instance` there. Expose you class object  through a `getter` method as below:

```
  class ClassName {

     private static ClassName myClass= null;

     public ClassName getClassName() {
       if(myClass == null){
         ClassName.myClass = new ClassName();
       }
       return ClassName.myClass;
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. That is like the opposite of a singleton. It guarantees that every thread will have it's own copy.

Comment: @user1522691: Remove the `ThreadLocal` and use the static variable of your class type itself.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like this:

```
class ClassName {

private static ClassName INSTANCE;

private ClassName() {
    //create ClassName object
}

public static ClassName getInstance(){
if (INSTANCE == null){
    INSTANCE = new ClassName();
} 

return INSTANCE;
}
```

}

Which is just a basic implementation of the singleton pattern.

If the class that constructs the object HAS to construct it using `new`, then you are kind of screwed. There is really no way to implement a singleton pattern in Java using only a public constructor.

**Edit**: You might be able to do something like this:

```
class ClassNameWrapper extends ClassName {

private final ClassName className;

public ClassNameWrapper(){
    className = ClassName.getInstance();
}

//overload methods from ClassName

}
```

This way, every call to `new ClassNameWrapper()` will be using the same instance of ClassName.